# assign more parameters to the existing environment in latex

Tags: macros

I have a .tex file as follows

```
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
C
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
```

I want to use the article class (or book) and the answer package (or something) to create a macro, after compiling to get a .tex file like this:

```
\begin{Solution}{1}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{2}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{3}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{4}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{5}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{6}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{7}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{8}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{9}
C
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{10}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{11}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{12}
A
\end{Solution}
```

Hope everyone help themselves!

Comment: If you want a numeration for the environment,  search about use LaTeX counters. If the solutions should be numbered like corresponding  questions elsewhere in the document, think in  `\label{key}`  and  `\ref{key}`  or `\pageref{key}`  for cross-references.

Comment: Thank you for reading and replying. Can you show me 1 macro to transfer? I need a macro

Comment: Without a working example is speculation, but likely the `Solution` environment is keeping track of its own numbering; you just have to access those numbers: `\begin{Solution}\label{sol:tenth}B\end{Solution}...In solution~\ref{sol:tenth}, we find...`

Comment: Thank you for reading and replying.

Comment: @HoacthanTran Edit the question to explain clearly your goal, more than the problem to the solution you have thought,  and show  us a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (i.e., a *minimal* document with only the relevant parts but *compilable* as is), where no one have to guess anything about the true scenario of the problem, only edit it to show you a possible solution.

Comment: If you need to link problem-texts and solution-texts, you can use the datatool-package, introducing a database with following fields: Primary Key, Name for referencing, Numbering of Problem/Solution, Text of problem, Text of Solution. Then you can define macros for extracting things from databae and nicely sorting/displaying them. But from your question it is not clear if this is what you need. If you clarify and specify your needs precisely, then I might elaborate and provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a .tex-file with a sequence of `Solution`-environments.

From that you wish to derive another .tex-file where `Solution`-environments have an argument right behind the environment-name which is used for providing consecutive numbering.

*(I suppose these numbers might be nominal-numbers (in contrast to cardinal numbers or ordinal numbers) so that each instance of the `Solution`-environment has an argument for its unique name, which can, e.g., be passed to `\label`-commands within the `Solution`-environment's definition.*

*Furthermore I suppose you have two preambles/frameworks for documents.

With the one of these preambles/frameworks the environment `Solution` is defined not to process any argument.

You have a .tex-file, which can be loaded via `\input`, where instances of  the `Solution`-environment fit that definition.

With the other of these preambles/frameworks the environment `Solution` is defined to process one argument.

With your .tex-file you need to adapt instances of the `Solution`-environment so that they can be used with that other framework.

Therefore an argument denting a (nominal-)number needs to be appended behind each sequence `\begin{Solution}`.)*

I think TeX is not best tool for this. There are editors/command-line-tools that can do search- and replace with regular expressions.

If you insist in using (La)TeX:  LaTeX3/expl3 has some nice regex-tools. LuaTeX-engines provide nice tools for pre-processing things before they are passed on to the traditional "TeX-digestion-tract".

**As a poorman's approach** I can offer a file to compile with LaTeX which does not provide a document but does provide a script/command for creating a copy of another .tex-file so that in the copy of that .tex-file `Solution`-environments are numbered consecutively. The command is:

```latex
\CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution{⟨source-file⟩}{⟨target-file⟩}
```

Copies *⟨source-file⟩* to *⟨target-file⟩*, appending `{⟨number⟩}` behind each instance of `\begin{Solution}`, so that in the *⟨target-file⟩* these instances are numbered consecutively, starting with number 1, and in the *⟨target-file⟩* things look like this: `\begin{Solution}{⟨number⟩}`.

"poorman's approach" because

- all tokens that form the entire content of the *⟨target-file⟩* are accumulated within a macro-argument before writing. This restricts the file-size.
- the phrase `\begin{Solution}` must look exactly like this. You can't have spaces or a linebreak between `\begin` and `{Solution}`. You can't have things like

  ```latex
  \begin{So%
  lu%
  %%%%
  tion}
  ```

  .
- the numbering always begins with 1.
- nesting `Solution`-environments inside `Solution`-environments is not taken into account.
- the fact that there might be places where appending numbering to the phrase `\begin{Solution}` is not desired, or where numbering should not be consecutive but should be repeated, e.g., inside the argument of a `\verb`-command, or inside a `verbatim`- or `listings`-environment, is not taken into account.
- a property immanent to TeX is that space-characters (code-point-number 32 both in ASCII and in unicode) at the right ends of lines will always be removed. This already happens in TeX's stage of pre-processing lines of .tex-input, even right before tokenization, thus there is nothing one can do about/against it.
  In case you used whatsoever editing-software for creating a .tex-input-file which has lines that end with space-characters, there is no way of using TeX for creating an exact copy of that file: In the copy these space-characters will be missing.
- with some characters TeX might produce ^^-notation when writing the target-file/the copy.
- writing in the source-file the single characters of the phrase `\begin{Solution}` via ^^-notation is not taken into account.
- hiding things by means of macros, e.g., `\def\foobar{Solution}...\begin{\foobar}...\end{\foobar}` is not taken into account.
- ...

```latex
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
% Just to make sure you have an external .tex-file which can be used as
%  <source-file> when applying 
% \CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution{<source-file>}{<target-file>}
% let's create a file testA.tex in the current directory via the
% filecontents*-environment:

\begin{filecontents*}{testA.tex}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
C D
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\end{filecontents*}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%  Now let's create a script providing a command
%
%  \CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution{<source-file>}{<target-file>}
%
%  which copies <source-file> to <target-file>, appending {<number>} behind
%  each instance of \begin{Solution}, so that these instances are numbered
%  consecutively, starting with number 1.

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange,
%% \UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace, \UD@checkstringsubsetof,
%% \UD@Scratchwrite
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\newwrite\UD@Scratchwrite
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does have a
%%                                       leading explicit space-token>}%
%%                                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                                       which is to be checked> does not have a
%%                                       a leading explicit space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {%
    % Let's nest things into \UD@firstoftwo{...}{} to make sure they are nested in braces
    % and thus do not disturb when the test is carried out within \halign/\valign:
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
      \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
      \string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB.#1 }{}%
    }{}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB{%
  \long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpaceB#1 {%
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
    {\UD@Exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
    {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}%
     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
  }%
}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Check if string of non-special character-tokens can be obtained by
%% truncating characters from the right side of another string or is equal to
%% other string:
%%===============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncating{<possible substring>}{<string>}%
%%   {<tokens if <possible substring> and <string> are equal>}%
%%   {<tokens if <possible substring> can be obtained by right-side-truncating characters from <string>>}%
%%   {<tokens if <possible substring> can not be obtained by right-side-truncating haracters from c<string>>}}%
%% The length of <possible substring> must not exceed the length of <string>!!!
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncating[5]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncatingloop#1\relax#2\relax{{#3}{#4}}{#5}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncatingloop{%
  \def\UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncatingloop#1#2\relax#3#4\relax{%
    \if\string#1\string#3\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \ifx\relax#2\relax\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
      {%
        \ifx\relax#4\relax\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
        {\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\UD@firstoftwo}%
      }%
      {\UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncatingloop#2\relax#4\relax}%
    }{\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution[2]{%
  % #1 source file  #2 target file
  \IfFileExists{"./#1"}{%
     \UD@PassFirstToSecond{%
        \begingroup
        \let\do\@makeother % <- this and the next line switch to
        \dospecials        %    verbatim-category-code-régime.
        \do\^^I%
        \do\^^M%
        \begingroup
        \everyeof{{XX}}%
        \begingroup
        \def\tempa{\endgroup\filereadandreplaceloop{1}{#2}{}{}}%
        \expandafter\tempa\@@input "./#1" %
        \endgroup
     }%
  }{%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Source-file `#1' does not exist in the\MessageBreak
                             current directory. Copying aborted}%
     \UD@PassFirstToSecond{}%
  }%
  {\IfFileExists{"./#2"}{%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Target-file `#2' already exists in the\MessageBreak
                             current directory. Not generating it from this source}%
  }}%
}%
\begingroup
\def\filereadandreplaceloop#1#2#3#4{%
  % #1 = catcode-12-character-token-string  "\begin{Solution}"
  % #2 = catcode-12-return/^^M
  % #3 = catcode-12-{
  % #4 = catcode-12-}
  \endgroup
  \@ifdefinable\UD@@trimtrailingendl{%
    \long\def\UD@@trimtrailingendl##1#2\UD@seldom##2\UD@SELDOM##3{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{##2}{\UD@stopromannumeral##3}{\UD@stopromannumeral##1}%
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\UD@trimtrailingendl[1]{%
    \romannumeral\UD@@trimtrailingendl##1\UD@seldom#2\UD@seldom\UD@SELDOM{##1}%
  }%
  \newcommand\filereadandreplaceloop[5]{%
    % ##1 = solution-number
    % ##2 = target-file
    % ##3 = text of target-file gathered so far
    % ##4 = Part of phrase \begin{Solution} gathered so far
    % ##5 = next character of source-file or XX
    \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}##5}{%
      \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingExplicitSpace\expandafter{\string##5}%
                                          {\filereadandreplaceloopb{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}}%
                                          {\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\string##5}{\filereadandreplaceloopb{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}}}%
    }{%
      \endgroup
      % Write ##3##4 to target-file ##2
      \@latex@warning@no@line{Writing file `./##2' to the current directory}%
      \begingroup
      \newlinechar=`\^^M %
      \immediate\openout\UD@Scratchwrite="./##2" %
      \immediate\write\UD@Scratchwrite{\UD@trimtrailingendl{##3##4}}%
      \immediate\closeout\UD@Scratchwrite
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
  \newcommand\filereadandreplaceloopb[5]{%
    % ##1 = solution-number
    % ##2 = target-file
    % ##3 = text of target-file gathered so far
    % ##4 = Part of phrase \begin{Solution} gathered so far
    % ##5 = next character of source-file as catcode-12-character
    \UD@CheckWhetherStringCanBeObtainedByRightTruncating{##4##5}{#1}{%
      %<tokens if <possible substring> and <string> are equal>
       \expandafter\filereadandreplaceloop\expandafter{\number\numexpr##1+1\relax}{##2}{##3##4##5#3##1#4}{}%
    }{%
      %<tokens if <possible substring> can be obtained by right-side-truncating characters from <string>>
      \filereadandreplaceloop{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4##5}%
    }{%
       %<tokens if <possible substring> can not be obtained by right-side-truncating haracters from c<string>>%
       \filereadandreplaceloop{##1}{##2}{##3##4##5}{}%
    }%
  }%
}%
% ======================================================================
% Temporarily change the catcode-régime and call
% \filereadandreplaceloop to close the group and redefine itself:
% ======================================================================
\def\@makeotherrecursion#1{%
  \ifx\@makeotherrecursion#1\else\@makeother#1\relax\expandafter\@makeotherrecursion\fi
}%
\UD@firstoftwo{%
  \@makeotherrecursion\\\b\e\g\i\n\{\S\o\l\u\t\i\o\n\}\^^M\@makeotherrecursion
  \catcode`\[=1
  \catcode`\]=2
  \filereadandreplaceloop
}{}[\begin{Solution}][^^M][{][}]%
\makeatother

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%  Now let's test the command defined in the script:

\CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution{testA.tex}{testB.tex}%

\stop
```

The `filecontents*`-environment creates a file **testA.tex** which looks as follows:

```
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
C D
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}
A
\end{Solution}
```

The command `\CopyFileAndAppendNumberToPhraseBeginSolution{testA.tex}{testB.tex}%` creates a file **testB.tex** which looks as follows:

```
\begin{Solution}{1}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{2}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{3}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{4}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{5}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{6}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{7}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{8}
A
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{9}
C D
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{10}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{11}
B
\end{Solution}
\begin{Solution}{12}
A
\end{Solution}
```

The syntax of the environment `Solution` in file **testA.tex** differs from the syntax of the environment `Solution` in file **testB.tex**.

Therefore the definition of the environment `Solution` at the time of `\input`ting **testA.tex** must differ from the definition of the environment `Solution` at the time of `\input`ting **testB.tex**.

Comment: Thanks for reading and everyone's help!